# Android: Adding a VectorDrawable to an ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, android-vectordrawable

So, I wanted to make a scroll-able worldmap with clickable countries. So when I found out there was a thing like `VectorDrawables`, I decided to give these a try.

Next thing I did was making a `VectorDrawable xml` file out of a `SVG` and tried to put it in my `ImageView`. While searching for some info, I found out that there were 101 ways to do this, and none of them worked for me... 
The interesting thing is that, when I add `"android:src="@raw/worldmap"` in the `ImageView` in my `activity.xml`, the map shows up in the preview, but whenever I try to run the app, it crashes.

```
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_show_hint"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.bert.myapplication.ShowHintActivity"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:scaleType="center"
        android:src="@raw/worldmap">
    </ImageView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Which OS are you running on?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 16.04.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, move your `VectorDrawable` to `Drawable` folder (not in raw). and then, add this line in your Gradle file :

```
defaultConfig{
vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
}
```

And finally, in your imageView, change to this;

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/img"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:scaleType="center"
       app:srcCompat="@drawable/worldmap">
    </ImageView>
```